# Run a WindowBuilder GUI from another class which also contains a JFrame

Tags: java, jpanel, actionlistener

So I am working on a project that needs a GUI; currently, I have a class which creates a JFrame with a flock of agents in it and these agents fly around the environment. I need to add a GUI to this JFrme so I can control the size of the flock as well as other items. 
I am using WindowBuilder in eclipse to create the GUI and I need to now 'attach' this GUI to the frame in the other class or, at the very least, have this GUI window running simultaneously with the other class so that when I run the application in eclipse, I can use the sliders to control the flock size then run the flock simulation, taking in the variable from the GUI.

I have been searching around online for quite some time trying to figure out how on earth to do this but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Code for Emre -> Thanks for the help so far! I have managed to get everything working regarding the JPanel but I am still having issues regarding the actionlistener for the "Run" button...I have included the amended code which contains an actionlistener for btnRun in the main class "Boids" - to me it looks like everything is correct and when run is pressed it should perform as expected but for whatever reason this button still isn't functional and I can't figure out why...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Boids extends JPanel {

    Flock flock;
    Flock flock2;
    final int w, h;

    public Boids() {
        w = 1200;
        h = 600;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        setBackground(Color.black);

        spawnFlock();
        spawnFlock2();

       new Timer(17, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (flock.hasLeftTheBuilding(w)) 
                spawnFlock();

            repaint();
       }).start(); 

        new Timer(18, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (flock2.hasLeftTheBuilding(w) && (flock.hasLeftTheBuilding(w)))

                spawnFlock2();
            repaint();
        }).start(); 
       //need to wait for the rest of the flock to leavebuilding before respawning leader, spawning is out of sync
    }


    public void spawnFlock() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int n = rand.nextInt(599) + 1;

//implement random for width as well as height


        flock = Flock.spawn(100, h - n, 20);
       flock2 = Flock.spawn(100, h - n, 1);

        }

    public void spawnFlock2() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        int n = rand.nextInt(599) + 1;

//implement random for width as well as height


     //   flock2 = Flock.spawn(100, h - n, 1);


        }



    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
        super.paintComponent(gg);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gg;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        SimGUI buttonx = new SimGUI();

        buttonx.btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1) {
                flock.run(g, w, h);

            }
        });


      //  flock.
     //   flock2.run(g, w, h); 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setTitle("Simulator v0.6");
            f.setResizable(false);
            f.add(new Boids(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
       //     f.add(new Boids(), BorderLayout.CENTER); to add another flock to environment 
            //leaders will also be added in this fashion
            f.pack();

            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
          //  SimGUI.getFrames();
          //  SimGUI test = new SimGUI();
          //  test.panel.setVisible(true);
            SimGUI test = new SimGUI();
            f.getContentPane().add(test, BorderLayout.EAST); //just positions a slither to the right, dont understand why it wont display jpanel -->
            //COULD THIS BE BECAUSE OF ME SETTING PREFERRED SIZE AND WIDTH/HEIGHT OUTSIDE OF MAIN? SEE "public Boids"...

         //SimGUI tempt = new SimGUI();
     //    tempt.setVisible(true);

        });



    }


 //   private void printPanelCompPoints(JPanel f) {
    //  f.getComponentAt(600, 500);
        //currently working on this = voting system
        //see psuedocode!
    }



//}

class Boid {

    static final Random r = new Random();
    static final Vec migrate = new Vec(0.02, 0);
    static final int size = 3;
    static final Path2D shape = new Path2D.Double();

    static {
        shape.moveTo(0, -size * 2);
        shape.lineTo(-size, size * 2);
        shape.lineTo(size, size * 2);
        shape.closePath();
    }

    final double maxForce, maxSpeed;

    Vec location, velocity, acceleration;
    private boolean included = true;

    Boid(double x, double y) {
        acceleration = new Vec();
        velocity = new Vec(r.nextInt(3) + 1, r.nextInt(3) - 1);
        location = new Vec(x, y);
        maxSpeed = 3.0;
        maxForce = 0.05;
    }
    void update() {
          velocity.add(acceleration);
            velocity.limit(maxSpeed);
            location.add(velocity);
            acceleration.mult(0);

    }

    void applyForce(Vec force) {
        acceleration.add(force);
    }

    Vec seek(Vec target) {
        Vec steer = Vec.sub(target, location);
        steer.normalize();
        steer.mult(maxSpeed);
        steer.sub(velocity);
        steer.limit(maxForce);
        return steer;
    }

    void flock(Graphics2D g, List<Boid> boids) {
        view(g, boids);

        Vec rule1 = separation(boids);
        Vec rule2 = alignment(boids);
        Vec rule3 = cohesion(boids);

        rule1.mult(2.5);
        rule2.mult(1.5);
        rule3.mult(1.3);

        applyForce(rule1);
        applyForce(rule2);
        applyForce(rule3);
        applyForce(migrate);


    }



    void view(Graphics2D g, List<Boid> boids) {
        double sightDistance = 100;
        double peripheryAngle = PI * 0.85;

        for (Boid b : boids) {
            b.included = false;

            if (b == this)
                continue;

            double d = Vec.dist(location, b.location);
            if (d <= 0 || d > sightDistance)
                continue;

            Vec lineOfSight = Vec.sub(b.location, location);

            double angle = Vec.angleBetween(lineOfSight, velocity);
            if (angle < peripheryAngle)
                b.included = true;
        }
    }

    Vec separation(List<Boid> boids) {
           double desiredSeparation = 25;

            Vec steer = new Vec(0, 0);
            int count = 0;
            for (Boid b : boids) {
                if (!b.included)
                    continue;

                double d = Vec.dist(location, b.location);
                if ((d > 0) && (d < desiredSeparation)) {
                    Vec diff = Vec.sub(location, b.location);
                    diff.normalize();
                    diff.div(d);        // weight by distance
                    steer.add(diff);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                steer.div(count);
            }

            if (steer.mag() > 0) {
                steer.normalize();
                steer.mult(maxSpeed);
                steer.sub(velocity);
                steer.limit(maxForce);
                return steer;
            }
            return new Vec(0, 0);
        }


    Vec alignment(List<Boid> boids) {
          double preferredDist = 50;

            Vec steer = new Vec(0, 0);
            int count = 0;

            for (Boid b : boids) {
                if (!b.included)
                    continue;

                double d = Vec.dist(location, b.location);
                if ((d > 0) && (d < preferredDist)) {
                    steer.add(b.velocity);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                steer.div(count);
                steer.normalize();
                steer.mult(maxSpeed);
                steer.sub(velocity);
                steer.limit(maxForce);
            }
            return steer;
        }

    Vec cohesion(List<Boid> boids) {
          double preferredDist = 50;

            Vec target = new Vec(0, 0);
            int count = 0;

            for (Boid b : boids) {
                if (!b.included)
                    continue;

                double d = Vec.dist(location, b.location);
                if ((d > 0) && (d < preferredDist)) {
                    target.add(b.location);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count > 0) {
                target.div(count);
                return seek(target);
            }
            return target;
        }


 /*   Vec avoid(List<Boid> boids) {
        int up = 0;
        int down = 0;

        for (Boid b : boids) {
            if (b.location.x + 100 > 600 ) {
                up = 1;
            }

        }







        return velocity = new Vec (0,1);
        } */

    void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        AffineTransform save = g.getTransform();

        g.translate(location.x, location.y);
        g.rotate(velocity.heading() + PI / 2);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fill(shape);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.draw(shape);

        g.setTransform(save);


        g.drawOval(600, 500, 75, 75);

    }




    void run(Graphics2D g, List<Boid> boids, int w, int h) {  //similair method to run leader 
        flock(g, boids);
        update();
        draw(g);

        //may need additional run method for leader
    }


}

class Flock {
    List<Boid> boids;

    Flock() {
        boids = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void run(Graphics2D g,  int w, int h) {
        for (Boid b : boids) {
            b.run(g, boids, w, h);

        }
    }

    boolean hasLeftTheBuilding(int w) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Boid b : boids) {
            if (b.location.x + Boid.size > w) //will also be used to calculate votes based on whether boids is near food
                count++;


        }
        return boids.size() == count;
    }




    void addBoid(Boid b) {
        boids.add(b);
    }

    static Flock spawn(double w, double h, int numBoids) {
        Flock flock = new Flock();
        for (int i = 0; i < numBoids; i++)
            flock.addBoid(new Boid(w, h));
        return flock;
    }



}

class Vec {
    double x, y;

    Vec() {
    }

    Vec(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    void add(Vec v) {
        x += v.x;
        y += v.y;
    }

    void sub(Vec v) {
        x -= v.x;
        y -= v.y;
    }

    void div(double val) {
        x /= val;
        y /= val;
    }

    void mult(double val) {
        x *= val;
        y *= val;
    }

    double mag() {
        return sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
    }

    double dot(Vec v) {
        return x * v.x + y * v.y;
    }

    void normalize() {
        double mag = mag();
        if (mag != 0) {
            x /= mag;
            y /= mag;
        }
    }

    void limit(double lim) {
        double mag = mag();
        if (mag != 0 && mag > lim) {
            x *= lim / mag;
            y *= lim / mag;
        }
    }

    double heading() {
        return atan2(y, x);
    }

    static Vec sub(Vec v, Vec v2) {
        return new Vec(v.x - v2.x, v.y - v2.y);
    }

    static double dist(Vec v, Vec v2) {
        return sqrt(pow(v.x - v2.x, 2) + pow(v.y - v2.y, 2));
    }

    static double angleBetween(Vec v, Vec v2) {
        return acos(v.dot(v2) / (v.mag() * v2.mag()));
    }
```

Working JPanel! ->

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.RowSpec;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpecs;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SimGUI extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    public JButton btnRun = new JButton("Run");

    public SimGUI() {

        JSlider sizeOfFlock = new JSlider();
        sizeOfFlock.setValue(10);
        sizeOfFlock.setMaximum(20);
        sizeOfFlock.setMinimum(1);






        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Settings");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Sitka Banner", Font.BOLD, 18));

        JLabel lblFlockSize = new JLabel("Flock Size");
        lblFlockSize.setFont(new Font("Sitka Heading", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("1");
        label.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("20");
        label_1.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JLabel lblTypesOfLeader = new JLabel("Types of Leader:");
        lblTypesOfLeader.setFont(new Font("Sitka Heading", Font.BOLD, 16));

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Spawn a leader inside the Flock");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Sitka Subheading", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JLabel lblSpawnAPersistant = new JLabel("Spawn a persistant leader");
        lblSpawnAPersistant.setFont(new Font("Sitka Subheading", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("");

        JCheckBox checkBox_1 = new JCheckBox("");

        JSlider noOfRuns = new JSlider();

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        textField.setText("" + noOfRuns.getValue());

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);
        textField_1.setText("" + sizeOfFlock.getValue());

        /**
         * Handle change event for sizeOfFlock slider.
         */


            sizeOfFlock.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    textField_1.setText(String.valueOf(sizeOfFlock.getValue()));
                }
         });

            textField_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                    String typed = textField_1.getText();
                    sizeOfFlock.setValue(0);
                    if(!typed.matches("\\d+") || typed.length() > 3) {
                        return;
                    }
                    int value = Integer.parseInt(typed);
                    sizeOfFlock.setValue(value);
                }
            });

            /**
             * Handle change event for noOfRuns slider.
             */

            noOfRuns.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        textField.setText(String.valueOf(noOfRuns.getValue()));
                    }
             });

                textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                    @Override
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                        String typed = textField.getText();
                        noOfRuns.setValue(0);
                        if(!typed.matches("\\d+") || typed.length() > 3) {
                            return;
                        }
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(typed);
                        noOfRuns.setValue(value);
                    }
                });



        JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("1");
        label_2.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("100");
        label_3.setFont(new Font("Sitka Display", Font.PLAIN, 14));



        JLabel lblNoOfSimulation = new JLabel("No. of runs");
        lblNoOfSimulation.setFont(new Font("Sitka Heading", Font.BOLD, 16));

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(this);
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(83)
                            .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                            .addGap(82)
                            .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(label, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 11, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(sizeOfFlock, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(label_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(lblFlockSize)))
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(lblNoOfSimulation)
                    .addContainerGap(207, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(label_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 11, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(2)
                    .addComponent(noOfRuns, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(label_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(6))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblTypesOfLeader)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1)
                            .addGap(18)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(checkBox_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(checkBox)))
                        .addComponent(lblSpawnAPersistant, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(86)
                    .addComponent(btnRun, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(136, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(5)
                            .addComponent(panel_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(lblNewLabel)))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 8, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(lblFlockSize)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(label, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(sizeOfFlock, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(label_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(28)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(lblTypesOfLeader)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1))
                        .addComponent(checkBox))
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblSpawnAPersistant, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(checkBox_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(30)
                    .addComponent(lblNoOfSimulation, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(noOfRuns, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(label_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(label_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addComponent(btnRun, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(225))
        );
        setLayout(groupLayout);





        };








    }
```

When the "Run" button is pressed it should execute flock.run(x,x,x) but despite my efforts this still wont perform as expected. I'm hoping you may be able to figure out why this is as I have been playing around with this for quite some time but have yet to get it working as expected

Comment: Normally you'd make all of your GUI components in the builder as JPanels, not JFrames.  JFrames are top level windows, and that's it.  They can't be anything else.  JPanels can be added to other components (esp. containers like other JPanels) allowing you to build GUIs kind of in the way you are describing.  It'll be a bit of a pita but I think you should just redo your current GUI as a JPanel.

Comment: As you can probably tell from the way I have written the question, I am terrible at programming however I have actually just figured out the first part (getting both of the classes with jframes to display at the same time) and your comment, I believe, has answered the second question, sort of - the gui is all but non existent so if I redo it in JPanel, how then would I add the jpanel to the original jframe? Would it be something like frame.add(guijpanel, borderlayout.left)? Thanks!

Comment: To answer your final question, basically yes, you have the right idea.  Emre's answer below is very good and also what I would do, at least absent any additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Make the GUI which you want to add to the JFrame a JPanel. Use it as a container to hold components you want to add to the GUI (buttons, labels, text areas etc.) After that call

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

JFrame's default layout is border layout. So JPanel will be placed center by deafult if you do not modify default behaviour.

If you want to add more than one JPanel to the same JFrame, then you should explicitly specify which panel goes to which area like

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.LEFT);
```

If you do not specify layout area, only the last panel added will be visible at the center.

For more than one container, I suggest to use one JPanel as main container and set its layout accordingly. Next add other components to main JPanel and then add only that JPanel to JFrame.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I have created the jpanel in a class called SimGUI and created the jpanel using the Jpanel panel = new jpanel however when I call the jpanel in the other class in main, it doesnt show up? I have set the border layout to east and it simply appears as a thin sliver on the side; I cant understand how/why this is happening. When I use windowbuilder to create the panel, the creation statement goes into public rather than public class and then I cant access the jpanel at all...sorry for the poor question but for something this basic its proving difficult

Comment: If you can add your code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Out at the moment but will do! Really appreciate the help

Comment: Hey there; as you can see I have just added the code to the question. I made a note regarding an action listener as I have had issues with this also but that isn't a primary concern - that remains the fact that the jpanel wont display es expected - many thanks

Comment: Change `f.getContentPane().add(test.panel_1, BorderLayout.EAST)` this line to `f.getContentPane().add(test, BorderLayout.EAST)`. You should add SimGUI object to frame since it extends JPanel. Afterwards you should implement action listeners accordingly. Take a look at this [link](https://ibb.co/kGkZSS).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help regarding the JPanel; i thought I was home free but for whatever reason I still can't get the actionlistener for the "run" button working as intended; would it be possible for you to take a look at it? I have made numerous attempts but none of them seem to work - either way, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: There is a problem with your code structure. You initiate a SimGUI instance from Boids class and then, try to reach that boids object within SimGUI. Although it is possible to create a getter for run button in SimGUI and add action listener to this button in Boids class, I don't think it is an elegant way to solve your problem. I would suggest creating JPanel which contains button inside Boids class and then add action listener to it inside Boids. This way, you will have access to the variables from Boids class you want to use in your actionPerformed method.

Comment: Hey Emre, thanks for the response. At the moment the best way I can figure to do this is by using getters like in the code above. When I press the button using the code above, it pains the boids/graphics in the SimGUI JPanel and not the Boids class environment. Do you know why this is?